# Show all elements of the inverse of $\text{tridiag}(-1,2,-1)$ are nonnegative

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am curious if there exists a cleaner way to prove this statement rather than by nasty calculation, i.e., using the algorithm of finding the inverse of tridiagonal matrix.

Comment: The inverse of a nonsingular M-matrix is nonnegative.

Comment: But this might make the problem even more complicated, because we need to show the statement about M-matrix is also true

Comment: not sure this is simpler, but maybe it is if you get used to it: http://www.phys.lsu.edu/~amarti9/adkadkakdf/241.%20Analytical%20Inversion%20of%20Symmetric%20Tridiagonal%20Matrices.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Assume that

- $A=B-C$, where $B$ is diagonal (with positive diagonal entries) and $C$ is non-negative,
- and let $A$ be strictly diagonally dominant, that is, $\|B^{-1}C\|_{\infty}<1$.

We have
$$
A^{-1}=(B-C)^{-1}=[B(I-B^{-1}C)]^{-1}=(I-B^{-1}C)^{-1}B^{-1}.
$$
Since $\|B^{-1}C\|_{\infty}<1$ and $(B^{-1}C)^i$ is nonnegative for all $i=0,1,2,\ldots$, we have
$$
(I-B^{-1}C)^{-1}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(B^{-1}C)^i\geq 0.
$$
Hence $A^{-1}\geq 0$.

NOTE: The statement above holds for *strictly* diagonally dominant matrices. Due to the continuity argument, it can be also extended to *weakly* diagonally dominant matrices such as the one in question.